# Query from two tables in report

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

My VB application prints a report via ODBC. I added the tables using database expert and designed the Crystal Report. Where do I put my query?
here is my query

```
SELECT ts.`SCHEDIDNO`,
       ts.`DAYNAME`,
       DATE_FORMAT(ts.`TIMESTART`, '%h:%i %p') as TIMESTART,
       DATE_FORMAT(ts.`TIMEEND`, '%h:%i %p') as TIMEEND,
       ts.`GRADELEVEL`,
       ts.`SECTIONNAME`,
       ts.`SUBJECTNAME`,
       ts.`FACFULLNAME`,
       ts.`ROOMNAME`,
       tf.`FACFULLNAME` as PERSONNEL,
       tf.`DEPARTMENT`,
       tse.`Adviser`
FROM `tblschedule` ts,
     `tblfaculty` tf,
      `tblsection` tse
WHERE ts.`GRADELEVEL` = " & lblgrade.Text & "
    AND ts.`SECTIONNAME` = '" & lblsect.Text & "'
    AND ts.`DEPARTMENTNAME` = tf.`DEPARTMENT`
    AND tf.`ADMINISTRATOR` = 1
    AND tse.`SECTIONNAME` = '" & lblsect.Text & "'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Crystal report wizard, locate your odbc created with username and password.

Then you will see a Command text, You can put your Query in there.

This code for VB.NET

```
 Private CRPT As New ReportDocument
    Private APPPATH As String
    Private PARAM As New ParameterFields
    Public PARAM_DESC As New ParameterDiscreteValue
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        APPPATH = Application.StartupPath & "\REPORT\sample.rpt"
        CRPT.Load(APPPATH)
        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CRPT

        PARAM = CRPT.ParameterFields

        PARAM_DESC.Value = Format(DatePicker1.Value, "yyyyMMdd")
        PARAM("DATEP").CurrentValues.Clear()
        PARAM("DATEP").CurrentValues.Add(PARAM_DESC)
        Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

This code is for C#:

```
CRPT = new ReportDocument();
            APPPATH = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "Sample.rpt";
            CRPT.Load(APPPATH);
            Report_Viewer.Refresh();
            CRPT.SetParameterValue("syear", Servercls.year);


            CRPT.SetParameterValue("smonth", Servercls.month);
            CRPT.SetParameterValue("sday", Servercls.day);
            CRPT.SetParameterValue("datevalue", Servercls.Datevalue);
            Report_Viewer.ReportSource = CRPT;

            sc.configureCrystalReport();
            Report_Viewer.Refresh();
```

Your crystal report parameter name must be the same with in your Code Behind.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try this later. :)

Comment: this is what i'm looking. thank you so much  sir. now i have one more  problem about the query in my where,  WHERE  stu.`SECTIONNAME` = {?sectiontext} And stu.`GRADELEVEL` = sch.`GRADELEVEL` AND `FACFULLNAME` = {?facultyname} AND sch.`GRADELEVEL` = {?glvl}
.how can i change the vale of "{?sectiontext}", {?facultyname}  and {?glvl} using a label from the form.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask some question. Thanks for appreciating

Comment: I'll tell you sir soon the result. and if i will encounter error.

Comment: Welcome just share you my thought.

Comment: Can you help me again.?? on my server pc the crystal works fine but on Client pc it prompts to logon on the database.

Comment: Yeah its prompt because you didn't set up the connection of your crystal report in client PC which is in Administrative tools > Data Source Odbc

Comment: You need to set it up with same connection name as your local machine

Comment: aw uk i'll try it later. Thankyou.