# Failed to open connection when exporting crystal report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to export my crystal report to pdf but keep getting the "failed to open a connection" error. It seems as if the error is happening at the CR.Export line.  I've tried everything but don't know how to fix it.  FYI, it's working on my development server, but when I copy it to the production server, I get the error.  So it's very hard to pin point where it's occurring.

```
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
    'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    Try

        InitializeComponent()
        strPermitNo = Session("RecordID")
        SpWithViewer(strPermitNo)
        CrystalReportViewer2.DataBind()

    Catch er As Exception
        LogError(er.ToString, "PageInit-PrintPermit1.aspx")
        Exit Try
    Finally

    End Try

End Sub
```

` 
Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

```
    strPermitNo = Session("RecordID")

    Try

        Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions

        Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()

        Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()

        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "\\idsfmsrvr\wwwroot\FWPDFs\" & strPermitNo & ".pdf"

        strAttachment = "\\idsfmsrvr\wwwroot\FWPDFs\" & strPermitNo & ".pdf"

        Session("Attachment") = strAttachment

        CrExportOptions = CR.ExportOptions

        If True Then
            CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
            CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
            CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions

            CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions

        End If
        CR.Export()
        EmailPermitToApplicant()
        File.Delete(strAttachment)
        lblMsg.Text = "Permit has been emailed to applicant."
        lblMsg.Visible = True

    Catch er As Exception
        LogError(er.ToString, "btnExport()-PrintPermit1.aspx")
        Exit Try
    Finally
        connFTS.Close()
    End Try`
```

Comment: Can you show here the exact error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a step:

> 1. Open a report first, follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099)
> 2. Export it whatever you want.

Take note: you can hide the form if you don't want to display the report.

Good Luck!

Comment: CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.InternalException: Failed to open the connection. Details: [Database Vendor Code: 4060 ] Failed to open the connection. FWPermit_5 {E97E0F6A-7F39-43A3-A1B6-3225E4F78289}.rpt Details: [Database Vendor Code: 4060 ] --->

Comment: Like I mentioned before, the exporting works in Development but not in production.

Comment: Check your network, connection string.. sometimes crystal report need to login into your working database before it shows and run.

Comment: @ Reds It's set to integrated security, so it doesn't require database login credentials.  So do I just leave it blank like....

Comment: 'CR.SetDatabaseLogon("", "")'

Comment: @ Reds, that worked.  I had to reconnect it in the page_init