# Crystal Report cross-tab report - getting the total for static columns

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a dataset getting from SQL server SP like below.

[image]

I need to put it in a cross tab report as I need to display the values in the category column as rows in the report.

Below is the format of the report I need.

Also I need to get the totals of all the rows in the report. I manage to get totals for dynamics columns but not for the Static columns (LastMonthSales and MarketReturn).

I used formula field, I can get the total but not in the same line as the other totals.

[image]

Comment: This cant be done, you need to pivot your query first before you proceed into crystal reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report Cross Tab tools only accept:

```
1. One specific Column.
2. One Specific Row.
```

> It cant be done with multiple different columns which is the other
>   column is came from rows. Best thing you have to do is to Pivot your
>   query to fit your needs.

Try to figure out this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenobonn/2009/03/22/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server/)

Comment: If I go for pivot table option, how can I map those columns into the datasource's datatable of the crystal report?

Comment: Follow this carefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099

Comment: Mapping cannot be done, because we dont know how many columns are coming from the database