# How to set Crystal Report Path which is in other folder in Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a form with `crystalreportviewer` in root folder of my project and my crystal report is inside 'Reports' folder. When I am trying to load my crystalreprot it's showing error. Here is my code...

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            ds = new InstallationReport();
            ds = PrintInstallationReport();
            ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[0]);            
            rptDoc.Load(@"F:\vs10\Windows\RapidDiagnostic\RapidDiagnostic\Reports\InstallationReport.rpt");
            //rptDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\InstallationReport.rpt");
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

It's showing the following error.
`A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack`

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can you post little more code? For example, how you initialize the rptDoc. Also, if you can provide the error message it would be helpful.

Comment: I think its looking in bin/debug/Reports where the executable is running from not the project root

Comment: Hi @MikaelKoskinen I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change report path into your project directory:

like this ====>>>>

```
APPPATH = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "Sample.rpt";
CRPT.Load(APPPATH);
```

> Make sure your report property => Copy to Output Directory => Copy if
>   newer

Rebuild your project then run.

After rebuild has been done you will find your crystal report file in bin => Debug folder in your project itself.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more info.

Comment: Hi @reds..... It worked but when I made setup file and installed it. Same Error came again.

Comment: Make sure your crystal report directory location is the same with your development PC.

Comment: It's showing the error....
`Load Report Failed. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack`

Comment: When I checked the Installation Destination Folder (C:\Program Files\MyProjectName) there is no `Reports` folder

Comment: Just include your report in your project deployed folder.. or you can copy and paste the report in there.. same with directory in your project development PC.