# Parameters not being passed correctly through code

Tags: c#, date, parameters, crystal-reports, report

My report gets data from a stored procedure. Two of the six parameters are dates (toDate and fromDate.) I integrate the report with C# Winforms and I pass the parameters through code the code with:

```
reportDocument.setParamterValue(0,paramValue);
```

The report works fine but does not render data despite showing the column header properly. When I refresh the report, it pops up the parameter window again. When I enter the parameters through that window the data shows, including column headers. But it doesn't work when I pass parameters through code.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
CRPT.SetParameterValue("smonth", Servercls.month);
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first of all call procedure in c# environment and save result in datatable and then send datatable to crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
First it was not working with setting parameters through indexing. so i set the parameters through name as reds suggested.
second i was missing the parameters binding with report viewer object. 
so i added the following line and it worked

```
crystalReportViewer.ParameterField.addRange(reportDocument.ParameterFields);
```

Thanks for the answers guys.