# .NET for Visual studio 2015 not refreshing data or filtering data as per parameters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have conducted a reasonable amount of searching relating to this problem but no solution has been found yet.

Basically, I have a Crystal report viewer in a C# Windows forms application which allows the user to browse to a .rpt and open it. All report files already have the data-source embedded.

Reports opens fine but ignores the parameters chosen and show all the data regardless of the parameters and does not work even after using the viewers refresh button.

I have confirmed that the reports (I have tried multiple reports from multiple difference data sources) have the option "Discard saved data" selected and the Save data with report option un-ticked.

Here is the core method that creates the viewer and opens the reports:

```
    public void Crviewer(string file)
    {
        
        Controls.Add(Menu());
        CrystalReportViewer tempViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
        ReportDocument tempCover = new ReportDocument();
        tempCover.Load(file);
       // tempCover.Refresh();
        ActiveForm.Size = new Size(1325, 658);
        tempViewer.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
        tempViewer.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        tempViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;//| System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
        tempViewer.Padding = new Padding(-1, 23, 0, 2);
        tempViewer.Name = "tempViewer";
        tempViewer.SelectionFormula = "";
        tempViewer.TabIndex = 0;
        tempViewer.ViewTimeSelectionFormula = "";
        tempViewer.ReportSource = tempCover;
        tempViewer.Refresh();
        //tempViewer.RefreshReport();
        tempViewer.Location = new Point(1325, 27);
        tempViewer.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(tempViewer);
}
```

Also please note the commented refresh method calls for both the report document and the viewer but neither of them worked.

Please note that I'm new to .NET development and might be missing something or going about it the wrong way.

Extra information that might be useful:

- SAP Crystal report runtime engine: `13.0.18.2192`
- SAP Crystal reports, version for VS: `13.0.17.2096`

Regards,

Neel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like I might have derped a bit....

All our reports filter records based on Selection formulas and because of the line:

```
tempViewer.SelectionFormula = "";
```

The Selection formulas were being overwritten.

-Neel

Answer (score 0):

I don't even see the parameter you mean:

When it comes to report parameter, It will look like this:

```
CRPT.SetParameterValue("syear", Servercls.year);
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more additional info.

Comment: I'm not passing the parameters through the code. Instead when you open the report it ask the user to choose/enter parameters from within the report.

Comment: Please see the edit/picture added to the original question for example.