# Printing w/o displaying Print Option Dialog Box Crystal Report Viewer in my C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# application that has a Crystal Report Viewer in a form. I call that form and pass to it a value that I use to update a parameter field associated with the Crystal Report so only a specific record gets displayed.

That all works fine, and I can call the Viewers PrintReport method to print the report without operator intervention.

```
CrystalForm fs = new CrystalForm(); 
fs.SetCrystalOrderNumParameter(ItemID);

 public partial class CrystalForm : Form
    {
        public CrystalForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetCrystalOrderNumParameter(string ItemID)
        {
            ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();

            ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
            ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            paramField.Name = "ItemID";
            paramDiscreteValue.Value = ItemID;
            paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
            paramFields.Add(paramField);


            crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

            crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();

        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that I want to be able to pass a value to the Crystal Report so that it uses this # to determine how many copies of the report should be printed.

Is there a way to do this using a Crystal Report Viewer ?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The crystal report viewer itself does not provide this functionality.

To control the number of pages without a dialog popup, you will have to use the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument` class.  This class is what the CrystalReports API uses to represent an actual Crystal Report, and it is usually assigned to the `ReportSource` property of the viewer to tell the viewer what report to display.  You may already be using this object, but I cannot see where you are assigning the report source from the code you have shared.

The `ReportDocument` class has a `PrintToPrinter` method, and the second overload looks like this: `void PrintToPrinter(int nCopies, bool collated, int startPageN, int endPageN)`

The `nCopies` parameter allows you to specify how many copies of the report to print.  The print settings for the report will default to whatever the report's printer settings are, though they may be changed via the `PrintOptions` property of the `ReportDocument` instance.

Here is a simple code example, where rptPath is the path to your crystal report:

```
var rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(rptPath);
rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "MyPrinterName";
//This will print 2 copies of the crystal report.
//You can use the nCopies (first) parameter to specify whatever #
//of copies you wish.
rpt.PrintToPrinter(2, false, 0, 0);
```

Additionally, when a ReportDocument is used to load a Crystal Report via the Load() method, it automatically populates its ParameterFields collection with all of the parameters that the report expects.  You can then set a parameter's value like reds displayed:

```
rpt.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", value);
```

Finally, if you want to show this report with the viewer, all you have to do is the following:

```
viewer.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Where `rpt` is the `ReportDocument` object representing the report, and viewer is the `CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer` you wish to use to display the report.

Comment: Brandon thank you for responding to my question.  The way I associate  a Crystal Report to my CrystalReportView, is after I drag a CrystalReportView component  to my form I click on the arrow that appears in the upper right hand corner of my form, and a properties dialog box shows that that allows me to choose an external Crystal Report to use.

Comment: Hmm, if you set a breakpoint in your SetCrystalOrderNumParameter function, and examine the ReportSource property of your report viewer, does it contain a ReportDocument object?  Maybe you can retrieve the document from the source and just call PrintToPrinter on that?

Comment: I am not familiar with using the visual studio designer to setup/display crystal reports.  Sorry I can't be more help on that end.

Comment: Thanks anyhow. I figured out how to incorporate the CrystalReportDocument into my app. Now I have to figure out how to change some of the printer option settings other than the # of pages to print.

Comment: The PrintOptions property contains all of the printer settings for the report.  Alternatively, you can use the overload for PrintToPrinter that accepts PrinterSettings and PageSettings as arguments.

Comment: Why is it when I bring up the page setup dialog box within Crystal Report my paper size is set to Horizontal=3 inch, and Vertical= 4, but when I do the same with the CrystalReportView inside by C# application , it shows a width of 3 inches and a Height of 2 ? Thanks again for all your help !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136982/discussion-between-brandon-kramer-and-l-levine).

Answer (score 0):

By passing a variable from code behind to cr report parameter:

It could be be like this:

```
CRPT.SetParameterValue("syear", Servercls.year);
CRPT.SetParameterValue("smonth", Servercls.month);
CRPT.SetParameterValue("sday", Servercls.day);
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more info