# Report keeps prompting for a value

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I add parameters to my report from my Data set Project .DLL

When using the parameter field in crystal, it keeps asking for values to be entered. The values were already set in the source before the data sets. How can I resolve this?

> IDE: Visual Studio 2013
>
> Crystal Version :  2013

We recently migrated from CR 2008.

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing:

> It is asking always cause you don't pass exactly the parameter value
>   into a parameter variable;

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) as your guide.

Comment: Make sure you pass the value correctly.. and set the parameter correctly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For response for this question, We found that one of our colleague set the data source for Report document Data fields, So it clears values for Parameters which is already set. So it keeps asking Value for Parameter, 
**Parameters should be Assigned only after setting the Data source for Report fields**. It will not ask for any value.

Thanks for your time and response.
Special thanks to the Edit, As i am new to this forum, I am still Figuring out the things.