# How to find what tables are used in SAP Crystal Report 2013?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to debug missing data in an existing report.

I see the database it is connected to, but I do not find any table or stored procedure or view in that database with the same name that I see in the record selection part of the Crystal Report.

Is there a way to find which table/view/stored procedure is used as input for the Crystal Report?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I found it. Rt click on **Database Fields** and select **Set Datasource location**...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up first what type of connection you need.

This will help you using [ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) connection.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can set this when first time confiugre the data, but suppose if you update the table or procedure and that will not impacted in your crystal report.

To update the updated db element / object in crystal report, simply "Update datasource" option click which pull the changes and update in crystal report.

May be helpfull in future.