# Missing parameter values in Crystal Report in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, crystal-reports

I am trying to pass a parameter from a Winform to Crystal Report, but I am getting this error

> Missing parameter Value

My code :

```
PrintCashReport cashreport = new PrintCashReport();
rptvwrcash.ReportSource = cashreport;

ParameterFields paramfields = new ParameterFields();
ParameterField type = new ParameterField();
type.Name = "type";

ParameterDiscreteValue dvtype = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
dvtype.Value = DailySalesReportBL.typeofrpt;
type.CurrentValues.Add(dvtype);
paramfields.Add(type);

rptvwrcash.ParameterFieldInfo = paramfields;

//PrintCashReport cashreport = new PrintCashReport();
cashreport.SetDataSource(ds);
cashreport.SetParameterValue("type", DailySalesReportBL.typeofrpt);

//rptvwrcash.ReportSource = cashreport;
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printDocument = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
cashreport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
cashreport.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T88V Receipt";
cashreport.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

I checked parameter's name in Crystal Report, that's fine too. I have checked value, it's getting the correct value too.

So please help me find out where I am getting it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you should set "paramfields.Add(...." after "cashreport.SetDataSource(ds)"!!

otherwise, the parameters are covered by "SetDataSource...."

Answer (score 1):

report parameter look like this:

```
CRPT.SetParameterValue("smonth", Servercls.month);
CRPT.SetParameterValue("sday", Servercls.day);
CRPT.SetParameterValue("datevalue", Servercls.Datevalue);
Report_Viewer.ReportSource = CRPT;
```

See this [Report Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more info.

Try this way:

```
ReportDocument  CRPT = new ReportDocument();
ParameterFields param = new ParameterFields();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramdesc = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
ParameterField paramfield = new ParameterField();
paramfield.Name = "type";

String APPPATH = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\CrystalReport1.rpt";
CRPT.Load(APPPATH);
param = CRPT.ParameterFields;
CRPT.ParameterFields.Add(paramfield);
param["type"].CurrentValues.Clear();
paramdecs.Value = "this is you crystal report parameter value value";
param["type"].CurrentValues.Add(paramdecs);

rv.ReportSource = CRPT;
```

Comment: so should I remove `ParameterFields paramfields = new ParameterFields();` till `rptvwrcash.ParameterFieldInfo = paramfields;` ?

Comment: Just comment your old code first then try to follow the new one

Comment: Do you have a parameter name "type" at your crystal report? or its just a type.name = "type"

Comment: Yes,Crystal Report has a Parameter named  `type` as String

Comment: I just noticed its a silly mistake I had 2 Parameters on Crystal Report of which values I was not passing , so removed it from Crsytal report and it works, sorry for miscommunication