# How to dynamically and correctly change a query in Command Table for Crystal Reports file?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have many rpt files. I want to change the query for each report using C#. There are several ways to do this changes.

#### First way:

```
private void button_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load("D:\\Temp_01\\Report1_Test.rpt");
    rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("User", "Password", "ServName", "DBName");
    CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo ConnInf;
    ConnInf = rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;
    String strSQLQuery = "SELECT TOP(123) * FROM sys.all_objects";
    String strTableName = rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].Name;
    try
    {
        rptDoc.SetSQLCommandTable(ConnInf, strTableName, strSQLQuery);
        rptDoc.VerifyDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { rptDoc.Close(); }
    rptDoc.SaveAs("D:\\Temp_02\\Report2_Test.rpt");
    rptDoc.Close();
}
```

It is not the best way. The method SetSQLCommand does not work when the query has any parameters. Even if you set value for each parameter, SetSQLCommand does not work. The example with a parameter which does not work:

```
private void button_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load("D:\\Temp_01\\Report1_Test.rpt");
    rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("User", "Password", "ServName", "DBName");
    CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo ConnInf;
    ConnInf = rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo;
    String strSQLQuery = "SELECT TOP(1) * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE name = {?strName}";
    String strTableName = rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].Name;
    try
    {
        rptDoc.SetParameterValue("strName", "Text");
        rptDoc.SetSQLCommandTable(ConnInf, strTableName, strSQLQuery);
        rptDoc.VerifyDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { rptDoc.Close(); }
    rptDoc.SaveAs("D:\\Temp_02\\Report2_Test.rpt");
    rptDoc.Close();
}
```

It returns an error. This method does not work with parameters!

#### Second way:

```
private void button_Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
    rptDoc.Load("D:\\Temp_01\\Report1_Test.rpt");
    rptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("User", "Password", "ServName", "DBName");
    ISCDReportClientDocument rcd = null;
    rcd = rptDoc.ReportClientDocument as ISCDReportClientDocument;
    CommandTable rTblOld;
    CommandTable rTblNew;
    rTblOld = rcd.Database.Tables[0] as CommandTable;
    rTblNew = rcd.Database.Tables[0].Clone(true) as CommandTable;
    rTblNew.CommandText = "SELECT TOP(1) * FROM sys.all_objects";
    try
    {
        rcd.DatabaseController.SetTableLocationEx(rTblOld, rTblNew);
        rcd.VerifyDatabase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { rcd.Close(); }
    rcd.SaveAs(rcd.DisplayName, "D:\\Temp_02\\", 1);
    rcd.Close();
}
```

This is also not the best way. The method SetLocalTableEx does a struct of the report is bad. After run SetLocalTableEx, attribute ConnectionInf.UserId have value NULL also the Name of connection

After SetTableLocationEx:

```
rcd.DatabaseController.SetTableLocationEx(rTblOld, rTblNew);
String UserID;
UserID = rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID;
if (UserID == null) MessageBox.Show("UserID has NULL");
```

UserId has value NULL

Also, before run SetTableLocationEx, Connection Name is MSODBCSQL11
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHNs7.png)

After run SetTableLocationEx, Connection Name is Command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePhaO.png)

So,
how do dynamic and correctly to change the query in CommandTable for Crystal Reports file?

Thanks,
Artem

Answer (score 0):

You are using command in `Crystal Report` which is the best way when doing and displaying a data from `database` to `crystal report` but unfortunately you do it in Code Behind.

My Question is:

> Why don't you do it in Command of `Crystal Report` itself?

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more info.