# Passing a parameter programmatically and displaying in crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in which I set the datasource and parameter programmatically but it is not working. I'm not getting the output as required.

**This is the output when i show all**

[image]

But when I pass parameters to it, it shows nothing.
I checked in DataTable by applying debugging the data is Filtered but it is not showing in my Crystal Report Viewer

**This is what I get when I passed parameters to it.**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataSet DataSet2 = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from personal_data WHERE class = '" + textBox1.Text.ToString()+"'", con);

    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

    DataSet2.DataSetName = "dt";
    DataSet2.AcceptChanges();

    DataSet2.Tables.Add(table);
    ad.SelectCommand=cmd;
    ad.Fill(DataSet2,"personal_table");


    ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
    // ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

    ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
    ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    paramField.Name = @"class";
    paramDiscreteValue.Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
    paramFields.Add(paramField);

    reportDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CrudStudent\Crud\CrystalReport1.rpt");
    crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
    reportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet2);
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Did you already create a parameter name "class" in your crystal report?

Comment: Yes, I already created it

Answer (score 0):

Passing a parameter look like this:

```
CRPT.SetParameterValue("parameterName", parameterValue);
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099) for more details.